# C# Web Request causes crash

Tags: c#, windows, web, request, response

I asked this earlier but none of the responses ended up working.
So I have a class that makes a web request to get a string of data, and a method in that class that calls the method to do that, then return the string value.

I have the MainPage class, a City Class(The WebRequest returns a JSON string and this class parses it and stores the data) and I have a WebRetrieval class.

In the MainPage I have this:

```
private void City_GoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    City cityObject = new City();
    WebRetrieval wr = new WebRetrieval();

    string jsonString;
    string formattedString;

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CityID_Textbox.Text))
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Please enter in a number");
        md.ShowAsync();
    }
    else 
    {
        long cityNum = Convert.ToInt64(CityID_Textbox.Text);
        string url = "http://honey.computing.dcu.ie/city/city.php?id=" + cityNum;

        jsonString =  wr.GetResult(url);
        formattedString = cityObject.ReturnFormattedString(jsonString);
    }
}
```

And in the Web Retrieval class I have this:

```
async public void GetInformation(string url)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
    result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

public string GetResult(string url)
{
    GetInformation(url);
    return result;
}
```

And what's weird is that, in the WebRetrieval class, inside of the GetInformation method, when it trys to do the response, the program jumps into my City class and fails because the string it received is null. It never makes it to the result line inside of the GetInformation method.

I have a feeling it is something to do with the fact that GetInformation is async and the response has await in it, but I don't know how to fix it as the suggestions in the other question didn't end up working.

Hopefully somebody can help me with this.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid `async void`. I explain the full details of "why" in my MSDN article [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

`void` is a very unnatural return type for `async` methods. You should only use it when writing an `async` event handler (which *must* return `void`).

So, converting all `async void` methods to `async Task` (and [following the naming convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
async public Task GetInformationAsync(string url)
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
  result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Those tasks must be `await`ed:

```
public string GetResult(string url)
{
  await GetInformationAsync(url);
  return result;
}
```

But then the compiler will complain that if you use `await`, you must make your method `async`, so we do:

```
public async Task<string> GetResultAsync(string url)
{
  await GetInformationAsync(url);
  return result;
}
```

And `await` that too:

```
private void City_GoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ...
  jsonString = await wr.GetResultAsync(url);
  formattedString = cityObject.ReturnFormattedString(jsonString);
}
```

Once again, the compiler complains, so we fix this by making the calling method `async` (normally, we'd make it `async Task`, but it has to be `async void` because it's an event handler):

```
private async void City_GoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ...
  jsonString = await wr.GetResultAsync(url);
  formattedString = cityObject.ReturnFormattedString(jsonString);
}
```

And you're done.

You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Comment: Wow what a great reply. This worked for me and explained it in a really good way! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that man!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, `GetResult` is calling `GetInformation`, which is an `async` method.  Basically, the internals of `GetResult` don't need to wait for the `GetInformation` call to complete in order to finish.  You have a timing issue.

Some possible solutions to this might be to either mark `GetResult` as `async`, and have it await `GetInformation`, or to have `GetInformation` return a value which you can then force to complete by calling `.Result` on the task.

Comment: Yeah I tried something similar to that but I don't know how to return a value in an async method? If I return a Task<string>, I can't convert it at the jsonString =  wr.GetResult(url); in the MainPage class.

Any way around this?

Comment: Async methods that return values should have a return type of `Task`.  For example, if you have a method with the signature `async public Task<string> GetInformation(...)`, you could simply return a `string`.  In your consumer code, you could write `Task<string> task = GetInformation();`, and then to ensure completion of the async method invocation, you would write `string result = task.Result;`  This might help as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh524395.aspx#BKMK_TaskTReturnType

Comment: @Thanks for that man I finally got it to compile.
However, the code seems to just stop at the response section in GetInformation. If I set a breakpoint before it, and go through it, when I try to go a step after var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));, my code just stops and it brings me back to the app. It seems the code just isn't running to finish still